# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404 - Angular 4 and Web API 2

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

In the service I am calling Web API(2)(hosted on different server than the front end angular 4 application) action method in order to retrieve some info.

The action method needs authorization which I am doing using access token that I receive after logging into the application. Now, the code works fine in Microsoft edge, however gives me preflight error in chrome which I guess is CORS issue. Not sure how to resolve this. Can someone help me with this?

Here is my code;

```
 getCompanyInfo(id: string) {
  let headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.commonService.accessToken
    });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  let getRequestUrl = this.commonService.baseUrl + 'api/getCompanyInfo';

    return this.http.get(getRequestUrl + '/' + id, options)
      .map((res: any) => <CompanyInfoModel>res.json())
      .do(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(this.commonService.handleError);
  }
```

Note that, this works fine;

1. If I do not use authorized access to Web API and remove the token from the headers.
2. In Microsoft edge with or without Access Token in headers.

Comment: I assume `this.http.get` takes care of making an OPTIONS request first on its own, if necessary? Have you checked in Chrome dev tools whether that actually happens?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for responding, I chrome dev tools I receive - Failed to load http://localhost:80/api/getCompanyInfo/1: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Comment: Do you see the actual preflight request (OPTIONS method) happening in network panel?

Comment: Do you have access to the other end of this as well, the server side of where the request is going to? If so, check the access and error logs there as well. This might be a quicker way of figuring out where this goes wrong.

Comment: @CBroe yes, I do have access to the server side. I can see the same 404 error in fiddler and in the network panel as well.

Comment: Am I missing something in my request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157734/discussion-between-learner-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing worked for me except the below; Where I had to import `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` and add this line of code at the top of ConfigureAuth method in `Startup.Auth.cs` of Web API.

```
 app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Please note:- remove all the settings for enabling CORS from `Web.config` and `WebApiConfig.cs`. Otherwise it will complain about duplicate implementation.

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: I am getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. even after adding the line above. If I add extra settings in config file to enable cores it says duplicate.

Comment: @bomaboom make sure you don't have any attribute related to core in your controller as well.

Comment: I don't have any attribute related to cores in the controller. BTW I get this error when I am making a call to the owin pipeline to get the token.

Comment: Can you post your front end call?

Comment: oAuthpostHttpMethod(relativePath: string, inputObject): Observable<any> {
    let body: string = this.encodeParams(inputObject); 
    return this.http.post(this.oAuthurl + relativePath, body,
      {headers:  new HttpHeaders(
      {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    )}
  );
}