# angular 5 cross origin issue with webapi

Tags: angular5

I have a registration page which uses angular 5 as front end and asp.net webapi as back end. I am getting an error message as follows.

"Failed to load http://localhost:2690/api/InsertParticipant: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400."

I think it is due to cross origin problem and I tried with header options like

Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Request-Method

And also I have chrome extension to resolve cors.

But still the problem remains unresolved.

Please help...
Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

On this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998227/response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404-angular-4-and-web-api?rq=1), the same is resolved by configuring cors.

I'm working with .net webapi 4.6.
I've also allowed all http calls to have acces to the webapi by below code, this worked for me.

```cs
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
```